# Fa Icon for html input

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a chat system and I was noticing the text overlapps my icon how can i prevent that from happening i want it to go to the next line before hitting the icon.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.message_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 93%;
  resize: none;
  left: 25%;
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.fa-paper-plane-o {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 92%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="2" cols="50" name="messages" class="message_box" placeholder="Write a message"></textarea>
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

No make any sense that you used `position: absolute`, but anyway, you can do a trick, wrap your `textarea` and `icon` with a `div` then use `float` to make both element side by side.

```css
.message_box {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    width: 92%;
    outline: none;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#Wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#Wrapper span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="Wrapper">
  <textarea rows="2" cols="50" name="messages" class="message_box" placeholder="Write a message"></textarea>
  <span><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: i think he used absolute positon to make the chat stay at the bottom of the page ... i think he want to build a kind of classic widget where chatting appear always on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to wrap everything inside a div that you make absolute and then manage the content inside it by using normal flow. You can then apply **padding**  to both side of textarea and use **negative margin** on icon for the overlap:

```css
.message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
  right: 0;
}

.message_box {
  resize: none;
  padding: 0 25px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fa-paper-plane-o {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="message">
  <textarea rows="2" cols="50" name="messages" class="message_box" placeholder="Write a message"></textarea>
  <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
</div>
```